# NSTextField - Insert Dashes

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

I need to insert a dash every 5 characters in a NSTextField. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Why the down vote? It's a reasonable question. +1 to counteract.

Comment: thanks Joshua. I don't understand some people here :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by subclassing NSTextField:

```
-(void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSString*value = [self stringValue];

    NSInteger integer = [[[self stringValue] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""] length];

    if (integer % 5 == 0)
    {
        value = [value stringByAppendingString:@"-"];
        [self setStringValue:value];
    }
}
```